# Finding the basis for the span of a given set of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the case of vectors we can form a matrix with columns as those vectors and find the reduced-row echelon form. A basis can be easily written from the given spanning vectors by looking at the pivotal rows of the reduced matrix.

But, is there a similar method if we are given spanning matrices? How to form the basis matrices of the space spanned by some given matrices?

Any hints are welcome and thanks in advance.

Comment: A 2 by 2 matrix is a 4 dimensional object...

Comment: Sir, Since a 2*2 matrix has four independent terms it is an element of a 4-D vector space. But, I didn't understand your hint regarding this question.

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR A space of matrices is isomorphic to a space of column vectors. Do the work in your space of column vectors and then apply the isomorphism.

Comment: ohh...yes!! Ok. thank you so much.